# Operand type clash: time is incompatible with int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a table, I have a column (AvgWaitTime) which stores data value in seconds (Data Type: float), date wise.  I have a function which performs some calculation using AvgWaitTime column and other few columns and returns a value in time format. I would to convert the value returned by the function (time format) into seconds (preferrably decimal, if not then int).

```
select 
(datepart(HH, dbo.fnGetMonthlyAverageWaitTime(m.RDate) * 60 * 60) +
datepart(mi, dbo.fnGetMonthlyAverageWaitTime(m.RDate) * 60) + 
datepart(s, dbo.fnGetMonthlyAverageWaitTime(m.RDate)))[MonthlyAverageWaitTime]
from TelephonyMTD m

Error: Operand type clash: time is incompatible with int
```

So, I tried to run this:

```
 select 
(datepart(HH, GetDate() * 60 * 60) +
datepart(mi, GetDate() * 60) + 
datepart(s, GetDate()))
```

Now it says, Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. Which is true when I looked at the data type conversion chart, I came to know that conversion to int and float is now allowed.

Please advice.

Comment: `GetDate() * 60`, may be you mean `...GetDate()) * 60`?

Comment: It might also be a good idea to get rid of the function, change it to an inline table valued function or if that doesn't work at least call it only once per every row.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to multiply a date/datetime by an integer which doesn't make sense:

```
GetDate() * 60 * 60
```

You could simply use `DATEDIFF` with seconds, to get the value in seconds:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00', dbo.fnGetMonthlyAverageWaitTime(m.RDate)) AS MonthlyAverageWaitTime
FROM    TelephonyMTD AS m
```

**QUICK EXAMPLE**

```
SELECT  t.AvgTime, 
        AvgTimeInSeconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00', t.AvgTime)
FROM    (VALUES
            (CAST('00:01:15' AS TIME)),
            (CAST('05:36:47' AS TIME))
        ) AS t (AvgTime);
```

Which gives:

```
+----------+------------------+
|  AvgTime | AvgTimeInSeconds |
+----------+------------------+
| 00:01:15 |        75        |
| 05:36:47 |       20207      |
+----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Open and Close brackets are the one causing issue for the above error: Please try like below

```
SELECT ( 
( Datepart(HH, Getdate()) * 60 * 60 ) + 
( Datepart(mi, Getdate()) * 60 ) + 
Datepart(s, Getdate()) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Below Syntax to convert `seconds` to `day, hour, minute, seconds`

```
DECLARE @sec INT = 86400;

SELECT 
     CAST(@sec /60/60/24 AS VARCHAR(12))  + ' Days,' 
  +  CAST(@sec /60/60 % 24 AS VARCHAR(12))+ ' Hours,'
  +  CAST(@sec /60 % 60 AS VARCHAR(2))    + ' Minutes, ' 
  +  CAST(@sec % 60 AS VARCHAR(2))        + ' Seconds.';
```